# Logging in sleep mode

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I periodically append logcat info to a file on my SD card, but it seems like it does not write anything to the file while the phone is in sleep mode.

I use `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to keep the cpu running.

Is it possible to write to a file on the SD card while the phone is in sleep mode (with a wake lock though) and if so, what am I missing?

Can add the code if wanted, but it doesn't seem relevant since it has already proven to work while the phone is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting notifications of when to write the log? If you are using Handler it doesn't work when the phone is in sleep mode. Use the AlarmManager service instead, it will work even if the phone is in sleep mode (and you won't have to worry about wake locks and potentially burning battery by keeping the phone out of sleep mode.)

Comment: i have a timertask scheduled to run every 30 seconds. I have other timertasks scheduled, and they all fire on time. 
the alarm manager seems more complicated, and as i understand i have to start up an activity with alarmmanager, with ui and everything?

Comment: @user755610, First of all, your approach with timetasks will not work when in sleep mode. You must have wakelock, otherwise your timetasks will not run in sleep mode. Second, `AlarmManager` is not bound to UI at all, you can send broadcast message or start service by `AlaramManager`.

Comment: "Im using a partial wake lock, to keep the cpu running."

Comment: I figured it out, i was using the default constructer when making a new FileWriter(File file), had to add the bool for append FileWriter(File file, Bool append)

Comment: It's good that you figured out the answer, but I think you should reconsider using a partial wake lock. By keeping the cpu running you are increasing battery usage. This is probably not a good idea if you want the app to run continuously. AlarmManager really isn't all that complicated.